# 1054 Unknown column 'Array' in 'field list'

Tags: php

Can someone help me with this error, when
1054 Unknown column 'Array' in 'field list'

```
[27-Oct-2021 09:15:04 Europe/Berlin] PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\joomla20\plugins\breezingforms_addons\gdata\gdata.php on line 398
```

The code is:

```
    $db->setQuery("Update #__breezingforms_addons_gdata Set
            `enabled`  = ".JRequest::getInt('gdata_enabled', 0).",
            ".($accessToken || $reset_accessToken ? "`password` = " . $db->quote($accessToken).',' : '')."
            `spreadsheet_id` = ".$db->quote(trim($gspid) == '' ? "''" : $gspid).",
            `worksheet_id` = ".$db->quote(trim($wid) == '' ? "''" : $wid).",
            `fields` = ".$db->quote($_POST['gdata_fields']).",
            `meta` = ".$db->quote($_POST['gdata_meta'])."
            ".($reset_accessToken ? ",`custom_client_id` = " . $db->quote("34263101371-4rcre0p6r9ehuhoat1d6ls8u84etuanp.apps.googleusercontent.com").', `custom_client_secret` = ' . $db->quote("IDq59sdLo6wC81KCUweDKVf2") : '')."
             Where form_id = " . intval($form_id) . "
        ");
        $db->query();
    }
```

The 398 line of code is:

```
    ".($accessToken || $reset_accessToken ? "`password` = " . $db->quote($accessToken).',' : '')."
```

What I do wrong?

Any help?

Comment: What is $accesToken and $reset_accesToken?

Comment: Check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57336194/codeigniter-unknown-column-array-in-field-list; maybe it can help.

Comment: "*Array to string conversion*" - one of the fields you are using in your query is actually an array, not a string. You need to find debug it and out which one.

Comment: You should use prepared statements for SQL queries with variables, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cant store an array, but for example you can store an array, ...

```
$accessToken = array(
   "username" => "text",
   "password" => "text",
);
```

like a json, ...

```
$accessToken = json_encode(array(
   "username" => "text",
   "password" => "text",
));
```

The result is a string (or a json) and you can store it into a database.

Comment: Hello sensorario, thank you very much, this your solution solved my problem :) you are the best! :)

Comment: @mirec Please accept my answer (click in the green check on the left) to mark question as solved

Comment: Hello, I did it, thanx for your help!

Comment: Hi sensorario, can you help me, with my question below?